# distinguish stdout from stderr on pipe

Tags: c, select, pipe

[popen() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743771/popen-alternative)

My question is related to one posted above. In the first/accepted response, we are doing:

```
// Child. Let's redirect its standard output to our pipe and replace process with tail
close(pipefd[0]);
dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(pipefd[1], STDERR_FILENO);
```

But what I want is to distinguish `ERROR` from regular `OUTPUT`. How can I do that? When I get anything in STDERR, I need to react to it.

It does not make much sense but, can I do following?:

```
int pipefd[3]     /* instead of 2 */

dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(pipefd[2], STDERR_FILENO);
```

I am using `select` to look at the fd and see if output is available. But till now, I just need to look at 1 fd, now I have to look at 2.

**NOTE**: A pipe can only have 2 ends, right? one to write to and other to read from. How can I accommodate this 3rd end :D ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two independent pipes and read from each of them separately. Shouldn't be hard since you already have a select() in place.

Comment: Thanks! Kinda makes sense. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Works pretty well! When I think about it now, this question itself is a bit `lame` but I guess I am stupid so its allowed :D! Much appreciated.