# Catching shell script output in program c

Tags: c, shell

I have C program ( program.c )  that calls a shell script ( command.sh ). 
command.sh returns an output (a password), i  need to get this output in my program.c.
using `system(command);` , i can't get hold of the output.
is there any other way in C to solve my problem?

Comment: Are you required to use `system()` (is this homework)?

Comment: @pilcrow i search for another way ,if exist. (this is not a homework;))

Comment: See this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output/646254#646254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `popen()` as suggested above, but note that in this case you have no control over the process you created (e.g. you will not be able to kill it), you also will not know its exit status.

I suggest using classical pipe/fork/exec combination. Then you will know the pid of your child process, so you will be able so send signals, also with `pipe()` you are able to redirect process standard output, so you can easily read it in your parent process. As example you can see my accepted answer to [popen() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743771/popen-alternative/6744256#6744256).

Answer (score 2):

Not in pure C. You want POSIX. Specifically `popen` function.

The specification has a nice example, that you can just copy 1:1 
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/popen.html

Comment: I hoped for a mechanism that uses the memory as intermediate between my program c and the script shell.I won't use files. Thank you

Comment: @Aymanadou Well yes, this solution is using a PIPE, that's just a buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're afraid to use libraries. Please try and use libraries, they're just as much part of Unix as shell tools.

Answer (score 2):

In pure C (well ... ignoring the contents of the `system()` call) you can redirect the shell script output to a file, then read that file.

```
system("whatever > file");
handle = fopen("file", "r");
/* if ok use handle */
fclose(handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should open a pipe using `popen` but this sounds tedious. A C program calling a shell script for a password.