# C++ Read Continous Command Output stream like tcpdump

Tags: c++, popen, outputstream

I would like to read the continuous output stream of commands like `tcpdump` from within a c++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


std::string outputcmd(std::string cmd){
    std::string data;
    char singlelinedata[1024];
    FILE * streamdata;
    streamdata = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    cmd.append(" 2>&1");
    std::cout << feof(streamdata);
    if(streamdata){
        while(!feof(streamdata)){
            // if(fgets(singlelinedata, 1024, streamdata)  != NULL ){
            //     data.append(singlelinedata);
            // }
            if(fread(singlelinedata, 1024, sizeof(singlelinedata)/sizeof(singlelinedata),streamdata)){
                data.append(singlelinedata);
            }
        }
        pclose(streamdata);
    }
    return data;
}

int main(){

    std::string outp;
    outp = outputcmd("sudo tcpdump -i any -v");
    std::cout << outp;
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving me only the first line output of `tcpdump -i any -v`

[image]

I dont want to `Write to file and read again` like following.
Make `tcpdump -i any -v -w myfile` to get it written on file and read continously

Comment: Maybe you need to retry after reaching `EOF` as the stream needs time to buffer?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `sizeof(singlelinedata)/sizeof(singlelinedata)` could be written more simply as `1`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: `data.append(singlelinedata);` is invalid. `singlelinedata` is not a C string. You need to actually use `fread`'s return value.

Comment: Your code doesn't give you any output as far as I can tell. It just sits there accumulating data, waiting for `tcpdump` to exit, which it never does. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @melpomene May be you are right, i have same thought, but do you know if thats true, What to do to collect the data from command output ? i am thinking to use pipe() and use pipefd[0] which is read, will that give stream of data?

Comment: You already have a stream of data: `streamdata`.

Comment: `cmd.append(" 2>&1");` after `popen` does nothing, the command is already running without it

Comment: @jakub_d true, it was part of experiments.

Comment: Your program will only print something once tcpdump has exited, try a `killall tcpdump`, you should see some results.

Comment: @jakub_d I am getting only the First line, and Last summary lines (Last Summary lines gets printed which i press CTRL + C    SIGNINT). [https://imgur.com/a/02R4hKU](https://imgur.com/a/02R4hKU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


void outputcmd(std::string cmd){
    char buffer[1024];
    FILE * pipef = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if(pipef){
        while(!feof(pipef)){
            int res;
            if((res = fread(buffer, /*note order here*/ 1, sizeof(buffer), pipef)) > 0){
                std::string block(buffer, res);
                std::cout << "read from pipe: [" << block << "] size " << block.size() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        pclose(pipef);
    }
}

int main(){
    outputcmd("sudo tcpdump -i any -v");
    return 0;
}
```

One note from the manpage

> Note that output popen() streams are block buffered by default.

so you will get the results with some delay and in big chunks, not line by line.

Comment: @jakub_b do you know when the popen() streams block is revoked during the execution?, (is it only when `tcpdump` sends close signal? ) or i can trigger forcefully to stop buffering and read buffer after every X seconds

Comment: @abdulrashid the note about block buffering means that you will get the data in blocks of 4096(?) bytes

Comment: @abdulrashid if you want a line-buffered analog of popen, you may need to make your own using fork&exec as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743771/popen-alternative

Comment: Thanks @jakub_d it worked. Also I found string has a constructor `std::string abc("My String")` from your reply